# Faking Entity Framework and attempting to LINQ query it gives error

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, repository-pattern

We have been trying to figure out how to fake the DbContext. So we followed the example here

http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/

And the code (one for the abstraction layer over EF (error below) and one directly using EF (works fine)...

All I can figure is maybe this has to do with the abstracted objects over top of the pre generated EF objects do not have a concept of relationship between tables/entities?? any idea?

We have just been trying to find some way to have a common path for our fakes and the real code.. maybe the easy answer is to stop doing it this way and just mock calls to the repository and then unit tests after that point ?

```
    CongressContext context = new CongressContext();
        var repo = new CongressRepository(context);

    //    IEnumerable<tMember> members = repo.Get100MembersDirectEF();
        IEnumerable<tMember> members = repo.Get100Members();
```

..............

```
 public class CongressRepository : ICongressRepository
{
    ICongressContext db;
    CongressDb_DevEntities realDb = new CongressDb_DevEntities();

    public CongressRepository()
    {
        this.db = new CongressContext();
    }
    public CongressRepository(ICongressContext context)
    {
        this.db = context;
    }

    public List<tMember> Get100Members()
    {
        var members = db.Members.Where(x => x.MembersID < 100).ToList();
        return members;
    }

    public List<tMember> Get100MembersDirectEF()
    {
        realDb.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        var members = realDb.tMembers.Where(x => x.MembersID < 100).ToList();
        return members;
    }





{"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nCongress.Data.tEducationType: : EntityType 'tEducationType' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tCongress: : EntityType 'tCongress' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tCongressMemPositionReason: : EntityType 'tCongressMemPositionReason' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tReasonType: : EntityType 'tReasonType' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tDistrict: : EntityType 'tDistrict' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tParty: : EntityType 'tParty' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tPosition: : EntityType 'tPosition' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tChamber: : EntityType 'tChamber' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tState: : EntityType 'tState' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tMemMilitary: : EntityType 'tMemMilitary' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tMemOccupation: : EntityType 'tMemOccupation' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tOccupationType: : EntityType 'tOccupationType' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tInterestGroup: : EntityType 'tInterestGroup' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tRaceType: : EntityType 'tRaceType' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nCongress.Data.tReligion: : EntityType 'tReligion' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\ntEducationTypes: EntityType: EntitySet 'tEducationTypes' is based on type 'tEducationType' that has no keys defined.\r\ntCongresses: EntityType: EntitySet 'tCongresses' is based on type 'tCongress' that has no keys defined.\r\ntCongressMemPositionReasons: EntityType: EntitySet 'tCongressMemPositionReasons' is based on type 'tCongressMemPositionReason' that has no keys defined.\r\ntReasonTypes: EntityType: EntitySet 'tReasonTypes' is based on type 'tReasonType' that has no keys defined.\r\ntDistricts: EntityType: EntitySet 'tDistricts' is based on type 'tDistrict' that has no keys defined.\r\ntParties: EntityType: EntitySet 'tParties' is based on type 'tParty' that has no keys defined.\r\ntPositions: EntityType: EntitySet 'tPositions' is based on type 'tPosition' that has no keys defined.\r\ntChambers: EntityType: EntitySet 'tChambers' is based on type 'tChamber' that has no keys defined.\r\ntStates: EntityType: EntitySet 'tStates' is based on type 'tState' that has no keys defined.\r\ntMemMilitaries: EntityType: EntitySet 'tMemMilitaries' is based on type 'tMemMilitary' that has no keys defined.\r\ntMemOccupations: EntityType: EntitySet 'tMemOccupations' is based on type 'tMemOccupation' that has no keys defined.\r\ntOccupationTypes: EntityType: EntitySet 'tOccupationTypes' is based on type 'tOccupationType' that has no keys defined.\r\ntInterestGroups: EntityType: EntitySet 'tInterestGroups' is based on type 'tInterestGroup' that has no keys defined.\r\ntRaceTypes: EntityType: EntitySet 'tRaceTypes' is based on type 'tRaceType' that has no keys defined.\r\ntReligions: EntityType: EntitySet 'tReligions' is based on type 'tReligion' that has no keys defined.\r\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way, instead of worrying about faking the context, fake the repository.

Real repository will be like this:

```
public class CongressRepository : ICongressRepository
{
    ICongressContext db;
    CongressDb_DevEntities realDb = new CongressDb_DevEntities();

    public CongressRepository()
    {
        this.db = new CongressContext();
    }
    public CongressRepository(ICongressContext context)
    {
        this.db = context;
    }

    public List<tMember> GetMembers()
    {
        realDb.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        var members = realDb.tMembers.Where(x => x.MembersID < 100).ToList();
        return members;
    }
}
```

Fake repository will be like this:

```
public class MockCongressRepository : ICongressRepository
{
    public List<tMember> GetMembers()
    {
         var members = new List<tMembers>{ new tMember { id = 1 } };
         return members;
    }
}
```

Unit test like this:

```
var controller = new CongressController(new MockCongressRepository());
```

Unit test using Moq:

```
    var mockCongressRepository = new Mock<ICongressRepository>();
    mockCongressReposiory.Setup(mcr => mcr.GetMembers())
                         .Returns(new List<tMembers>{ new tMember { id = 1 } });        
    var controller = new CongressController(mockCongressRepository.Object);
```

Note: Here we got rid of the **MockCongressRepository** class and the mock is defined close to the unit test.

Comment: Yes.. I think that is more the standerd approach.. But I think the disadvantage of that is you can't unit test the linq queries ... But since the linq2Entity query is really integration testing and not unit testing then I shouldn't be trying to do that anyways?? So yes at the moment we will try the classic way you mention.. What about using Moq?  How does that apply to all of this ?

Comment: Yes you are right. You shouldn't be testing linq2Entity stuff.

Comment: Moq is just a way of making fake/mock classes. Following from the above example, instead of creating `MockCongressRepository` you can use Moq, to create a mock close to your unit test. I have added an example to my answer above.